# Searching data is null

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I am using jqGrid 4.6, but i laso tried this on latest version 5.1.0.
I have such definition of searchoptions:

```
loadComplete: function() {
    var keys = grid.getGridParam('colModel');
    for (var i=1; i<keys.length; i++) {
        var cellname = keys[i].name;
        grid.setColProp(cellname, {
            searchoptions: {                
                dataUrl: 'RData_io.php?action=filter&field=' + cellname,
                sopt: ['eq', 'ne', 'lt', 'gt', 'le', 'ge', 'cn', 'nc'],
                postData: grid.getGridParam('postData')
            }
        });
    }       
}
```

dataUrl gives me correct select, and value is loaded correctly inside dropdownbox after some small amount of time.
We get something like this:
[image: Search window]

Seems fine, but, when we click the "Find" button, we have such params posted to the server:

```
filters:"{"groupOp":"AND","rules":[{"field":"week1","op":"eq","data":null}]}"
```

So, as you can see, "Pass", is not posted to server. Altough, if we change to "Fail", and then back to "Pass" - it's working fine.

Can you help me, [Oleg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/315935/oleg)?

Thank you,
Zakhar

**UPDATE**: If you are using not Free-jqGrid from Oleg, but some old version, or <= 5.1.0. You can use this trick, something same as @Oleg proposed, but as selectFilled do not let you to use option, use this instead:

```
selectFilled: function (options) {
    $('.input-elm').change();
},
```

Comment: I recommend you to try with [free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid) 4.13.2 - it's the fork of jqGrid, which I develop and provide under the same license for free as 4.6. You can for example to use free jqGrid from CDN (see [the wiki article](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki/Access-free-jqGrid-from-different-CDNs)). If you will have the same problem, then please create the demo, which use `jquery.jqgrid.src.js` instead of `jquery.jqgrid.min.js`. I will debug it and help you.

Comment: Hello, Oleg. Thanks for your reply, I already thought about this. Will try it tomorrow, and write you about the results!

Comment: OK! Till tomorrow...

Comment: @Oleg, I've almost made a demo. But I am stuck on simulating ajax-requests for dataUrl. Is there is a way to send them using POST-method to use jsfiddle /echo/html/? See at https://jsfiddle.net/mxct4bdu/3/

Comment: I introduced the callback `selectFilled` in **free jqGrid** already in the version 4.8.0. I examined the corresponding sources of Guriddo jqGrid JS and I see that Tony added only jQuery UI event `jqGridAddEditAfterSelectUrlComplete` (see [here](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v5.1.0/js/grid.common.js#L475)), which one can use, but no `selectFilled` callback exist.

Comment: @Oleg selectFilled and my proposed solution works for me at jqGrid 4.6.0 :)

Comment: You should not believe your tests. See [the line](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/blob/v4.13.2/js/grid.common.js#L486) of free jqGrid code, which call `selectFilled` callback and trigger `jqGridSelectFilled` event. Then examine the code of jqGrid 4.6 near [the place](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/blob/v4.6.0/js/grid.common.js#L388). You fill find no `selectFilled`. The problem which you report depend on the timing of response from `dataUrl`. The effect exist only if `dataUrl` response in not in cache and if the response come slowly (use `delay` > 0 in jsfiddle).

Comment: @Oleg, I see. I've made investigation and: you can call the function as you want (if it's not defined already), and it will fire on complete of dataUrl ajax-call. I didn't get deep into the source, why it happens, but it works somehow. Don't know, if we should concentrate on this: better use newer version. And if someone want to get the fix on an old one - here it goes :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see the problem on the demo. It's a bug in jqGrid. Thank you for the bug report!

I'll fix it tomorrow, but one can still use an additional feature of free jqGrid as the workaround. One can use `selectFilled` callback which trigger `change` event *after* the select is successfully loaded from `dataUrl`

```
selectFilled: function (options) {
    $(options.elem).change();
}
```

The corresponding `searchoptions` option will looks like

```
searchoptions: {
    clearSearch: false,
    selectFilled: function (options) {
        $(options.elem).change();
    },
    dataUrl: '/echo/html/',
    sopt: ['eq', 'ne', 'lt', 'gt', 'le', 'ge', 'cn', 'nc'],
    postData: { 
        html: "<select><option>Pass</option></select>",
        delay: 0
    }
}
```

One can verify that the fixed demo use correct `data` in the filter `rules`: https://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/mxct4bdu/7/

**UPDATED:** I fixed the bug on GitHub sources (see [the commit](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/commit/f1b1616000a98a786f3c966fe845f36e956b506b)). Now the demo without the workaround with `selectFilled: function (options) { $(options.elem).change(); }` works correctly. See https://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/mxct4bdu/8/

Comment: Thank you, @Oleg! Strange, that no one else have found this bug! But, glad to hear, that now we managed to make jqGrid a bit better :)

Comment: I also see, that if you open Search dialog one more time, select is not filled for some reason for you version of jQgrid. Something is missing?

Comment: @freeek: What you mean exactly? Which demo you used (https://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/mxct4bdu/8/ or your code which used HTTP GET instead of HTTP PUT?) If you use HTTP GET then please verify HTTP headers (Caching) which you use in the response from `dataUrl`. What behavior you need to have (Caching or reloading `dataUrl` response every time)?

Comment: yes, I used this fiddle, but it;s working now, sorry :) 
May be it was my internal (or jsfiddles) problems!
P.S. It also would be nice, if you post here a link, how to reload filters every time, I am thinking of doing this.

Comment: @freeek: I'm not sure what you mean. What kind of reloading of the filters you mean? The old versions versions of jqGrid and free jqGrid could used `recreateFilter: true` option of Searching Dialog, but the options is not more used in free jqGrid starting with version 4.13.0 - the option will be used *always*.

Comment: ah, I see. that's why I though select (I called it filter, sorry), is lost. It's just always recreated from the server!